# Best RAID Config for Hyper-V using 3x 750GB 7200RPM SATA Drives?

Tags: virtualization, raid, hyper-v

I am looking to virtualize 3 - 5 small low resource servers to one Dual QuadCore box.  The box currently has 3x 750GB drives available.  What would be the best RAID config?  I am leaning toward RAID1 but wanted to get other opinions before I pulled the trigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buy a fourth disk, RAID 10 them. I know it's not what you want to hear but it's the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

RAID 1 with a hot spare, unless you want to take Chopper3's path.

Answer (score 2):

The RAID1 (tripple mirror in that case) where all disk hold the same data will give you the most resiliency and be very biased towards reads.

Just listen to Chopper3's answer. It's what you really want.